# Find the first value that meet a defined criteria

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset on Coivd-19 cases and deaths by day and country. I wish to find the date when the first death occured for every country, and the filter away all the preceding days. How would you tackle this problem in R/Tidyverse?

```
library(readxl)
library(httr)
url <- paste("https://www.ecdc.europa.eu/sites/default/files/documents/COVID-19-geographic-disbtribution-worldwide-",format(Sys.time(), "%Y-%m-%d"), ".xlsx", sep = "")
GET(url, authenticate(":", ":", type="ntlm"), write_disk(tf <- tempfile(fileext = ".xlsx")))
df <- read_excel(tf)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(dplyr) 
# or library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  arrange(`Countries and territories`, DateRep) %>%
  group_by(`Countries and territories`) %>%
  mutate(Cumulative_Death = cumsum(Deaths)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(Cumulative_Death > 0) %>%
  group_by(`Countries and territories`) %>%
  mutate(First_Death_Date = min(DateRep))
```

It adds new columns `Cumulative_Death` : sum of death up-to `DateRep` and `First_Death_Date`: date when the first death occured for every country

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
      arrange(DateRep) %>% 
      distinct(`Countries and territories`, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

I think this is the simplest option for you. `dplyr::distinct()` removes all but the first row, so if you arrange the data by the desired column you'll get the first match only. `.keep_all = TRUE` will keep all columns, not just those specified in `distinct()`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, But I dont really understand this logic. And it dosent seam to return What I want :)